# Why can't go parse the time represented by the provided formats?

Tags: parsing, time, go

Consider this example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(time.Parse(time.RFC3339, time.RFC3339))
}
```

The output is:

```
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC parsing time "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": extra text: 07:00
```

Why can't time.Parse() handle a layout as a value? What's missing here?

---

**UPDATE:** Cutting off the time zone value (but not the 'Z' delimiting the time from the zone) fixes it:

```
fmt.Println(time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2015-09-15T11:50:00Z"))
```

Why can't time.Parse() handle time zone info when using time.RFC3339 as the layout string?

http://play.golang.org/p/p3fHfJNHVK

---

**UPDATE:** JimB's answer led me to read from RFC3339 and I found these examples that clarify further:

Here are some examples of Internet date/time format.

> `1985-04-12T23:20:50.52Z`
>
> This represents 20 minutes and 50.52 seconds after the 23rd hour of
>   April 12th, 1985 in UTC.
>
> `1996-12-19T16:39:57-08:00`
>
> This represents 39 minutes and 57 seconds after the 16th hour of
>   December 19th, 1996 with an offset of -08:00 from UTC (Pacific
>   Standard Time).  Note that this is equivalent to `1996-12-20T00:39:57Z`
>   in UTC.

Comment: Is it helpful? https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9346

Comment: Yes, that was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `time.RFC3339` format is a case where the format string itself isn't a valid time. You can't have a `Z` *and* an offset in the time string, but the format string has both because the spec can contain either type of timezone specification.

Both of these are valid RFC3339 times:

```
"2015-09-15T14:00:12-00:00"
"2015-09-15T14:00:13Z"
```

And the time package needs to be able to parse them both using the same RFC3339 format string.

Comment: Based on your response it seems the example in the package documentation for RFC3339 is wrong. https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants

Answer (score 8):

As noted, `2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00` is an invalid [IETF RFC-3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) time format. Here's an explanation.

The reason you cannot have both Z and an offset is that they are both ways to represent a time offset. `Z` is equivalent to `+00:00` indicating a zero hour/minute offset, or no offset. You cannot say both `+00:00` offset and `+07:00` offset in the same time representation.

The following is the `Z` definition in the RFC-3339 Section 2:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-2

```
Z  A suffix which, when applied to a time, denotes a UTC
   offset of 00:00; often spoken "Zulu" from the ICAO
   phonetic alphabet representation of the letter "Z".
```

Of note, while `Z` is equivalent to `+00:00`, they are both different from `-00:00` which indicates known UTC time with an unknown offset, as described in RFC-3339 Section 4.3:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-4.3

```
4.3. Unknown Local Offset Convention

   If the time in UTC is known, but the offset to local time is unknown,
   this can be represented with an offset of "-00:00".  This differs
   semantically from an offset of "Z" or "+00:00", which imply that UTC
   is the preferred reference point for the specified time.  RFC2822
   [IMAIL-UPDATE] describes a similar convention for email.
```